# How to simplify list of Graphics options?

Tags: graphics, options

When looking at the internals of graphics expressions we often see that some options like `PlotRange`, `Frame`, `Ticks`, `PlotRangePadding` etc. are repeated several times in the list, and sometimes even have different values. For example:

```
gr = LogLogPlot[x^2 + x^3, {x, 1, 100}];
Cases[Options[gr], _[Ticks, _]]
Cases[Options[gr], _[DisplayFunction, _]]
```

> ```
> {Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Log", {Log, Exp}, "Nice", 
>     WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, RotateLabel -> 0], 
>    Charting`ScaledTicks["Log", {Log, Exp}, "Nice", 
>     WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, RotateLabel -> 0]}, 
>  Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}
>
> {DisplayFunction -> Identity, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
>  DisplayFunction -> Identity, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
>  DisplayFunction -> Identity, DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
>  DisplayFunction :> Identity}
> ```

In the above example, the option `Ticks` appears two times with different values, and the option `DisplayFunction` appears 7 (!) times with identical values.

When inspecting the low-level structure of *Mathematica* graphics, such duplicated options litter the source code and often make it difficult to find out which value of duplicated option actually "works".

Is there a safe way to remove all the trash from the list of options, leaving only those option specifications which actually work? I know that we can obtain actual value for every particular option by specifying it explicitly in the second argument of `Options`, but I wish to leave only the options which are already present in the expression.

A super-requirement would be the ability to remove non-actual options: for example, if we have set `Axes -> False`, then options like `AxesOrigin`, `AxesStyle`, `Ticks` do nothing and we can safely remove them from the expression source code for the purposes of readability.

---

**UPDATE**

I just found that `Options` has a bug: it extracts options from the first argument of `Graphics` too, for example:

```
gr = Graphics[{Ticks -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1}, 
  {Axes -> True}, {{Ticks -> {Automatic, None}}}, Ticks -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> .2]
Options[gr, {Ticks, AspectRatio}]
```

> [image: graphics]

> ```
> {Ticks -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1}
> ```

As one can see, `Options` takes the requested option values from the first argument of `Graphics` - where they are ignored by the renderer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the easiest part my first attempt is:

```
Clear[simplifyOptions]
simplifyOptions[(h : Graphics | Graphics3D)[first_, rest__]] := 
 h[first, DeleteDuplicatesBy[First[#, #] &]@Flatten[{rest}]]
```

It completely avoids both the bug in `Options` and its check-up for the correctness of the options list (I do not wish to fix wrong options, since it is intended for visual inspection of the source code).